# Build boost without version number suffixes

Tags: android, c++, boost, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I want to build boost libraries for android, shared version. After a lot of struggle I managed in the intent. However, when packaging the libraries inside my application I cannot have them with the suffix with the version number after the .so extension. And I cannot simply rename the files as they link to each other by referring to the name *with* the suffix.

How can I get rid of the version suffix when building boost libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-devel-archive/ECzpXasvfVs), the solution is:

In boostcpp.jam, find the line `if $(type) = SHARED_LIB &&` and, just below, remove `.$(BOOST_VERSION)` from `result` computation:

```
    if $(type) = SHARED_LIB &&
      ! [ $(property-set).get <target-os> ] in windows cygwin darwin aix &&
      ! [ $(property-set).get <toolset> ] in pgi
    {
        result = $(result).$(BOOST_VERSION)  ;
    }
```

(You can in fact comment the entire section)